# Rewrite needed in htaccess file?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm using a wordpress site and have tested my paged links, which work fine, however, the issue I think I'm having is in the url.  How do I get a link that keeps appearing like this:

http://.........../dealer-login/dealer-data/2/

to appear like this:

http://.........../dealer-login/dealer-data?page=2

Something keeps changing this when I attempt to go to the next page.  When I pass the page variable the first time (which takes me to dealer-data?page=1) it works beautifully.  It's only when you attempt to navigate to subsequent pages that it displays '/2/' which I believe is causing the issue?

htaccess:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteBase / 
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
 </IfModule> 
 # END WordPress
```

Permalinks are currently set to 'post name' - I've changed that around a couple of times to see if one of the other selections would work.

Comment: You need to provide more information. There's obviously something changing it. There is no way for any one to guess unless they had the **exact** same issue. What are the rules of your .htaccess file and are you using any type of SEO plugins?

Comment: no SEO plugins installed

Comment: Update your question with the htaccess rules instead of in the comments so that it's legible. Aren't you using some type of permalinks?

Comment: Are yo actually talking about a rewrite here or simply that the Wordpress app is generating links to the second page using the `*/2/` format?  You should not fight against the SEO-friendly URL structure that you seem to be using in Wordpress by default.

Comment: I need the url to say ?page=2 though so that it loads page 2 of my sql query.  I can pass this in the the url the first time, but when I click "next" or any of my pagination links, it just reloads page 1....and I think it is because the url says /2/ as opposed to ?page=2